# How To Get Value Last Day of Last Month that Have Value

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello so i need help to develop my program, this is about SQL Query in Oracle, i need to search data from last day of the month that have value,

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM RATE
WHERE CCY_SHORTNAME = 'USD'
AND RATE_DATE = LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yy'), -1))
```

It'll give me data that have ccy_shortname = usd and on the last day of the last month which is 31 August, the problem is in i can't get any response when i decrease the month by 2 month (-2), which is 31 July, cause in 31 July in my country is holiday, so it doesn't have data in that date, the data in 30 July, i want to get value in 30 July, so what is the query to retrieve data of the last day of the last month that have data?

UPDATE :

For Anyone wonder what i used, i'm end up using this code.

```
SELECT * FROM RATE 
WHERE RATE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(RATE_DATE) FROM RATE
                   WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(RATE_DATE),'yyyyMM') = 
                   TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-1)),'yyyyMM'))
```

Thanks for anyone who mind to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I understood it (sample data from line #1 - 6; query you might need begins at line #7):

```
SQL> with rate (rate_date, value, ccy_shortname) as
  2    (select date '2020-07-29', 100, 'USD' from dual union all
  3     select date '2020-07-30', 105, 'USD' from dual union all
  4     select date '2020-08-03', 115, 'USD' from dual union all
  5     select date '2020-08-04', 120, 'USD' from dual
  6    )
  7  select *
  8  from rate a
  9  where a.rate_date = (select max(b.rate_date)
 10                       from rate b
 11                       where b.ccy_shortname = a.ccy_shortname
 12                         and b.rate_date <= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'mm'), -1) - 1
 13                      );

RATE_DATE       VALUE CCY
---------- ---------- ---
30.07.2020        105 USD

SQL>
```

By the way, it doesn't make sense in `TO_DATE`-in a `SYSDATE` which is a function that returns `DATE` value anyway.

Comment: This one help me, thanks man, appreciate that so much

Answer (score 0):

This should work but I don't have data to test it. Idea is to search between 1st day and last day of the month and then find the max data where count is greater than 0 i.e. record exist.

```
SELECT * FROM RATE
WHERE CCY_SHORTNAME = 'USD'
AND RATE_DATE = (SELECT MAX(RATE_DATE) FROM RATE WHERE CCY_SHORTNAME = 'USD' 
AND RATE_DATE BETWEEN (LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yy'), -2)) +1) AND LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(to_date(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yy'), -1))
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, i do have the answer, hehe

Answer (score 0):

**First day of Previous Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 2 month) + interval 1 day
```

**Last day of Previous Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month)
```

**First day of Current Month**

```
select last_day(curdate() - interval 1 month) + interval 1 day
```

**Last day of Current Month**

```
select last_day(curdate())
```

Comment: Thanks for your time answering my question, but i have the answer from Littlefoot, thank you

Comment: There are no such functions (DATEADD, DATEDIFF, GETDATE) in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend window functions:

```
select *
from (select r.*,
             max(r.rate_date) over (partition by short_day) as last_day
      from rate r
      where r.rate_date < add_months(trunc(r.sysdate), -2)  -- or whatever
     ) r
where rate_date = last_day and
      short_day = ?;
```